# Create a WordPress template without navigation and footer

Tags: templates

As the title suggests, I'd like a page template to have NO navigation and NO footer.

All my page templates have this:

```
<?php
 /*
   * Template Name: Blah Blah
 */

 if (!defined('ABSPATH'))
  exit; // Exit if accessed directly
 get_header();
 ?>
```

But if I remove the above code then the entire page won't work.

Comment: downvoted and close voted as this will be totally theme dependent. (bravokeyl answer is really the best answer possible but it is only the starting point)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't remove `get_header()`.

Duplicate the `header.php` to `header-{custom-name}.php`, let's say (`header-nonavfooter.php`) then in the template file replace `get_header()` with **`get_header('nonavfooter')`**.

In the new header file (`header-nonavfooter.php`) remove the code related to navigation.

Do the same for the `footer.php` also(Create a new footer.php and remove the footer parts that you don't need), remember not to remove `wp_footer()` available in `footer.php`.

Comment: the "get_header('nonavfooter')" idea worked great - but I can't seem to find how and where the footer is called. * sorry - i figured it out :)