# Trying to create a template without navigation and footer

Tags: templates

This relates to this previously asked [question.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/276143/create-a-wordpress-template-without-navigation-and-footer)

I followed exactly the advice given but it doesn't seem to work?

The advice was: *"Duplicate the header.php to header-{custom-name}.php, let's say (header-nonavfooter.php) then in the template file replace get_header() with get_header('nonavfooter'). In the new header file (header-nonavfooter.php) remove the code related to navigation."*

At the top of the template I'd like to have no navigation or footer is this:

```
<?php
/*
* Template Name: No Navigation/ No Header
*/

if (!defined('ABSPATH'))
exit; // Exit if accessed directly
get_header('headerremoved');
?>
```

I created a file called **headerremoved.php** (with the removed navigation) but it still loads the navigation which suggests this template is loading the original header...

Very confused why it isn't working - is there something I should be looking for to problem-solve here?

+++

My headerremoved.php (named like that) is like this:

```
<?php
if (!defined('ABSPATH'))
exit; // Exit if accessed directly
/**
* The Header for our theme
*
* Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div 
id="main">
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage
* @since 2015
*/
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) & !(IE 8)]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-
 scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="<?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri()); ?>/js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- GTM IC 20170805 -->
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
  })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','XXX');</script>

    <!-- <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<!-- GTM IC 20170805 -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=XXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>

<!-- navigation removed -->
```

The top of my template file looks like this:

```
<?php
/*
* Template Name: No Header
*/

if (!defined('ABSPATH'))
exit; // Exit if accessed directly
get_header('header-headerremoved');
?>
```

Comment: Try and remove the `get_header()` line completely. What happens?

Comment: It breaks the entire theme/ css...

The strange thing is that I had it working but I renamed the file with the removed navigation and I can't recreate how to do it. I've checked multiple times for typo's etc

Comment: Any chance of having a look into your `headerremoved.php` file? By the  way, the file name should be `header-headerremoved.php` to work.

Comment: sure - thanks - i've updated the question to show the code

Comment: I meant the file's name, not the call to it :) When you use `get_header('header-headerremoved');`, WordPress will automatically add a `header-` prefix, and look for the file. For example, it will look for `header-header-headerremoved.php` in your case. So, rename your file to `header-headerremoved.php`, and use `get_header('headerremoved');`

Comment: Wow - awesome - thanks v much that solved it....I thought it was a simple naming convention issue. Saved me a bunch of time! I was unaware that WP appends the 'header' before the filename path...thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look into the codex page for [`get_header()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) function, you will notice that WordPress automatically adds a `header-` prefix to your call. For example, using this:

```
get_header('sample');
```

Will search for the `header-sample.php` file. So, in your case, you should name your header file `header-headerremoved.php` and then call it the following way:

```
get_header('headerremoved');
```